# Consuming soap api in sharepoint

Tags: sharepoint-online, soap, api

I am getting data in xml formal by hitting the below url in browser.

`https://test.oracleoutsourcing.com/api/widget/test/GetESSDataOP?userId=302`

I wanted to know how would I be able to read this data in sharepoint and utilize it to perform some other operation like adding data to list.

Answer (score 1):

after hitting url you will get xml data like below 
https://test.oracleoutsourcing.com/api/widget/test/GetESSDataOP?userId=302

```
{
   "value": [
     { 
       "IdName": "test@test.onmicrosoft.com",
       "Workphone": "1234567891",
       "Title": "it",
     }
   ]
}
```

so you can consume using CSOM or JS code as per key value like :

propertyMap.Add("Property1", "Workphone");

propertyMap.Add("Property2", "Title");